# I can't seem to add checkbox value to db

Tags: php

I am creating several checkboxes from sql values

```
<?php
    $i=0;
    $query5= "SELECT * FROM sales_price WHERE product_id = $currentid";
    $choices5 = $conn->query($query5);
        foreach($choices5 as $choice5){
        ?>
    <input type="checkbox" id="gift<?php echo $i; ?>" name="gift[<?php echo $i; ?>]['gft']" value="<?php echo $choice5['price_name']; ?>">
    <label for="gift<?php echo $i; ?>" style="margin-right:15px"><?php echo $choice5['price_name']; ?></label>
     <?php $i++; 
    }  ?>
```

for example:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="gift1" name="gift[1]['gft']" value="small">
<label for="gift1" style="margin-right:15px">small</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="gift2" name="gift[2]['gft']" value="medium">
<label for="gift2" style="margin-right:15px">medium</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="gift3" name="gift[3]['gft']" value="large">
<label for="gift3" style="margin-right:15px">large</label>
```

The whole thing is inside a `<form method="post">`
I am trying to add the checked value into the db with

```
foreach($_POST['gift'] as $gifts){
$stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO cart_gifts(cart_id, gift) VALUES (:ucartid, :ugift)');
$stmt->bindParam(':ucartid', $last_id);
$stmt->bindParam(':ugift', $gifts['gft']);
if($stmt->execute()){   
echo "<script>window.history.back()</script>";
}
}
```

But I am facing the following issue, the code does go through and does it's loops inputs 3 rows (as per example) to the table with columns ID (A.I.) , Cart_id, gift, it adds ID and ofc the cart_id but the gift column stays null and also if only one checkbox is checked it still inputs all three.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep name for every check box input same.

```
<?php
$i=0;
$query5= "SELECT * FROM sales_price WHERE product_id = $currentid";
$choices5 = $conn->query($query5);
    foreach($choices5 as $choice5){
    ?>
<input type="checkbox" id="gift<?php echo $i; ?>" name="gift[]" value="<?php echo $choice5['price_name']; ?>">
<label for="gift<?php echo $i; ?>" style="margin-right:15px"><?php echo $choice5['price_name']; ?></label>
 <?php $i++; 
}  
?>
```

This will look like

```
    <input type="checkbox" id="gift1" name="gift[]" value="small">
    <label for="gift1" style="margin-right:15px">small</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="gift2" name="gift[]" value="medium">
    <label for="gift2" style="margin-right:15px">medium</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="gift3" name="gift[]" value="large">
    <label for="gift3" style="margin-right:15px">large</label>
```

And at the time of binding parameters use

```
$stmt->bindParam(':ugift', $gifts);
```

Comment: It worked like a charm, I had a small issue but was due to my loops and I fixed it. Thank you very much.